# Yarn 3 - Allow engines warning?

Tags: yarnpkg, package.json

In yarn 1 if you added the [engines property](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#engines) to your package.json, and you were using the wrong version of node, yarn would error.

[It appears that they have removed this functionality since yarn 2.](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6627)

Is there a configuration property to return this behaviour - even if just a warning?

The context where I want this is tests fail on Node 16, but not node 14, so I want to hint at 'Hey make sure you're using node 14'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for the engines property in package.json indeed seems to be removed since Yarn 2. There is an open feature request to Yarn for returning the check, see https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/1177.

Until the feature is re-added to Yarn 2+, you could try using the [yarn-plugin-engines](https://github.com/devoto13/yarn-plugin-engines) plugin to return the behaviour.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.